# Typescript: typing a function with an array of functions that returns an array of each function return type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible for the code below to be typed correctly?

```
function arrayElementTypes(...array: Array<(() => string) | (() => number) | (() => {prop: string}) | (() => number[])>) {
   /// .. do something
   /// .. and then return an array with each functions result
   return array.map(arg => arg())
}

const [varA, varB, varC] = arrayElementTypes( () => "", () => ({prop: "prop"}), () => [1,2,3] )
// how can this be typed appropriately so that the : 
// varA: string
// varB: {prop: string}
// varC: number[]
```

Comment: It's hard to know what "typed correctly" means. You're passing in a set of functions that have varying parameter counts, so `array.map(arg => arg())` is invalid for the last function type in your array union. You also only pass in 3 functions but are looking for a returned array of length 4. Are you expecting to destructure the returned array into individual types (as if it were a tuple) or an intersection of the return types of the functions (as if it were an array)?

Comment: corrected the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do it with

```
type ReturnTypes<T extends Array<(...a: any[]) => any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any[]) => infer R ? R : never
}

type CustomArrayElement = (() => string) | (() => number) | (() => {prop: string}) | (() => number[])

function arrayElementTypes<T extends CustomArrayElement[]>(...array: T): ReturnTypes<typeof array> {
   return array.map(arg => arg())
}

const [varA, varB, varC] = arrayElementTypes( () => "", () => ({prop: "prop"}), () => [1,2,3] )
```

Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not optimistic that it can be typed correctly. Firstly, I think you are looking at a *tuple*, rather than an array, since the "array" of functions have different signatures, and you want the return type of `arrayElementTypes` to correspond to the return type of each function in the "array", matching *position-wise*.

At the same time, I hesitate to say it's impossible outright, as I've seen [amazing things](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579#issuecomment-710776922) that can be done using a combination of generics and conditional types.

---

**Edit:** I have come up with some "building-block" types that may help with the final answer, but you can see if you can piece them together :)

```js
// any function
type Fn = () => unknown;

// a tuple/array of functions
type FnArr = readonly Fn[];

// the first function in your tuple of functions
type Head<T extends FnArr> = T extends [infer HeadFn, ...any[]] ? HeadFn : never;

// the rest of the functions in your tuple of functions
type Tail<T extends FnArr> = T extends [any, ...infer TailFns] ? TailFns : never;
```

Using the above building blocks, you can extract the return types of each function in your tuple of functions. This doesn't directly lend itself to a solution, but maybe some recursively defined conditional types (to generalise for arbitrary tuple of functions) can get you there :)

```js
const [varA, varB, varC] = arrayElementTypes( () => "", () => ({prop: "prop"}), () => [1,2,3] )
// how can this be typed appropriately so that the : 
// varA: string
// varB: {prop: string}
// varC: number[]

type ExampleFns = [ () => string, () => {prop: "prop"}, () => number[] ];

type TypeForVarA = ReturnType<Head<ExampleFns>>;                // F1 = string
type TypeForVarB = ReturnType<Head<Tail<ExampleFns>>>;          // F2 = {prop: "prop"}
type TypeForVarC = ReturnType<Head<Tail<Tail<ExampleFns>>>>;    // F3 = number[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [varA, varB, varC, varD]: Array<string | number | {prop: string} | number[]> = arrayElementTypes( () => "", () => ({prop: "prop"}), () => [1,2,3] )
```

Does this satisfy your requirements?